# Google AdMob interstitial ads in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, admob, windows-phone-7.1, ads

I want to add  google ads in my project but my project is for windows phone 7 . how can I implement GoogleAdMob to my windows phone 7 application. also I want to implement google interstitial ads in my application how can I did that???
I had a try to upgrade my project from 7.1 to windows phone 8 but it can't run it shows error like it
I have developed HubTile Application. which used coading4fun toolkit and  wpcontrolls.toolkit

> "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Reflection.CustomAttributeData' to >type 'System.ComponentModel.TypeConverterAttribute'

and please tell me if  there is any other ad network which provide interstitial ads to windows phone 7 application which have good eCPM . please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Google Admob is only available on windows phone 8, android and ios.

Support for windows phone 7 was dropped in 2013.

Until then, you can either use one or a combination of the following:

```
Microsoft PubCenter
Ad Duplex
inMobi
Leadbolt
Scoreoid
Mediabrix
PreApps
```

More [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uk_faculty_connection/archive/2014/04/07/adding-ads-into-apps-and-games.aspx)

You can also use [AdRotator](http://wp7adrotator.codeplex.com/) to achieve a +99% fill rate by real time swapping/replacing of ad providers.

Comment: Any ad provider which provides full screen Ads when app launch and closed in windows phone 7??

Comment: Almost all of the ad networks above provide interstitial & rich media ads(full screen ads).